# How to get the Status of the LCA using Its ETA CaseNumber?

Tags: labor

Is there any option by using API provided by DOL that makes it possible to get the Status and PDF from Icert Site using ETA Case Number?

Answer (score 0):

The following HTTP request should get you what you are looking for:

```
https://icert.doleta.gov/index.cfm?
event=ehRegister.caseStatusSearchGridData
&page=1
&rows=30
&sidx=case_number
&sord=asc
&_search=false
&nd=1507270449320
&caseNumberList=pipe|separated|case|numbers
```